# jquery replace < with " " (a space)

Tags: jquery, function, forms, blur

I'm trying to replace the characters `<` and `>` onblur with a space when someone enters it into my form.

I've got this at the moment

```
$(".tbAddress").blur(function() 
{ 
    $("<").replaceWith(" ");
    $(">").replaceWith(" ");
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(.tbAddress).blur(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace("<"," "));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(">",' "));
});
```

If your RegEx-Fu is better than mine, you can combine the two lines and pass in a Regular Expression as the first parameter to `replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tbAddress").blur(function() 
{
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[<>]/, ' '); 
}
```